# What is the correct entry point for capturing coverage data

Tags: plugins, php, hooks, debug

I am on a mission to find out which plugins are used on a large wordpress installation. Furthermore i need to find out which parts of which plugin is used exactly.

So i decided to record some code coverage data using the php-xdebug plugin.

```
<?php
xdebug_start_code_coverage();
/**
...
*/
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
file_put_contents("coverage_report/coverage_".time().".json",json_encode(xdebug_get_code_coverage()));
xdebug_stop_code_coverage();
```

So that gives me a lot of information already and it basically works. But i noticed, that some parts of plugins that i definetly know are being used are not reported here. Especially those parts that are registered in the "init" hook in wordpress seem to not show up in the coverage report. I have plugins that send a redirect in those init hook functions.

My question is: is the index.php the right place to put those calls ? Or is the another place where i can catch EVERY request made to the wordpress system ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not how coverage should be tested, or probably not even what it means. coverage "testing" is part of having a testing plan and the coverage information lets you know how good your testing plan is (for some definition of good, as rarely a 100% coverage is worth achieving in a complex code).

What you are doing is more of a profiling, which is a worthy information by itself, but it is not actually related to coverage.